# Probability: Random Variables and Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

1) The function: $F(x)=k(1-(1/2)^{[x]})$, $x > 0$

Is the distribution function for a discrete random variable X. Here, [x] denotes the integer part of x (i.e., the greatest integer less than or equal to x).

a) Determine the value of k.

b) Specify the probability mass function of X.

---

2) The function: $F(x)=k(1 - \frac{1}{x^2})$, $1 \leq x < 2$

is the distribution function for a continuous random variable X. Determine the value of k and the probability density function for X.

*I'm super lost, this probability class makes no sense to me what so ever. Can someone please explain how to solve these or provide a solution to the 2 problems? Thanks...*

Comment: Please check what values x can take on for #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $X$ is continuous and if the distribution function or cumulative distribution function is given as $F_X(x)$, then the probability distribution function is given as $f_X(x) = F'_X(x)$.

Also, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1$ by definition (either that or it follows from Kolmogorov axioms. I think).

If $X$ is discrete, then $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} f_X(x) = 1$. For the pdf, see [slide 7](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~ciardo/teaching/CS177/section6.1.pdf) here. Never knew about this in Elem Prob or maybe I just forgot. lol.

Comment: Note that for #2 this is true; however, this is not (necessarily) true for #1.

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks!

Comment: @Clarinetist How do you get the pdf of a cdf of a discrete RV? Advanced Probability made me forget all the artificial distinction in elem prob :( *searches google meanwhile*

Comment: @Clarinetist Okay I found that you just have to get the difference? Seems too easy, but I guess that that is kind of the discrete version of the derivative (if the derivative is not considered the continuous version of difference)

Comment: To get the probability (mass) function $\mathbb{P}\left(X = k\right) = p_{k}$ (assume $k \in \mathbb{Z}$) from the CDF $F(x) = \sum\limits_{k \leq x}p_{k}$, notice that $F(x) - F(x-1) = \sum\limits_{k \leq x}p_{k} - \sum\limits_{k \leq x-1}p_{k} = p_{x}$.

Comment: I'm not a math major. All of these comments have seemed like gibberish to me thus far. :P

Comment: @Clarinetist Can $x$ be $\in [0,1)$ then?

Comment: @user127662 Ignore the comments then :))

Comment: @BCLC: Well, if $x \in [0, 1)$, $x = 0$ since $X$ is a discrete random variable - that is, $X \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Clarinetist And what of $x-1$? It's gonna be negative...

Comment: @BCLC - Oops. For problem #1, since $X$ is discrete, $X$ can only take on integer values. We're given, furthermore, that $X > 0$. So therefore, $X$ can only take on the values $1, 2, 3, \dots$.

Comment: @Clarinetist How do you know it is discrete? Isn't the whole point of the floor function to accommodate non-integers?

Comment: @BCLC: It states in 1: "The function $F(x)$... is the distribution function for a *discrete* random variable $X$." [I have no idea what use the floor function is, honestly.]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17391/discussion-between-clarinetist-and-bclc).